# MYSQL: Exclude duplicate scan logs within same day

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to select rows excluding duplicates in a day.
Criteria for duplicate is: `SAME USER` AND  `SAME PRODUCT_UPC` AND `SAME DATE(SCANNED_ON)`

So, from the below table, if SCAN_ID = 100 is selected, exclude SCAN_ID = 101 since they belong to same user_id AND same product_upc AND have same DATE(scanned_on).

Here's the table structure:

```
SCAN_ID      USER_ID      PRODUCT_UPC      SCANNED_ON
100          1            0767914767       2020-08-01 03:49:11
101          1            0767914767       2020-08-01 03:58:28
102          2            0064432050       2020-08-02 04:01:31
103          3            0804169977       2020-08-10 04:08:48
104          4            0875523846       2020-08-10 05:21:32
105          4            0007850492       2020-08-12 07:10:05
```

Query I've come up so far is:

```sql
SET @last_user='', @last_upc='', @last_date='';
SELECT *,
@last_user as last_user , @last_user:=user_id as this_user,
@last_upc as last_upc , @last_upc:=product_upc as this_upc,
@last_date as last_date , @last_date:=DATE(scanned_on) as this_date
FROM scansv2
HAVING this_user != last_user OR this_upc != last_upc OR this_date != last_date
```

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: @nbk I'm using 5.7, but I'm open to upgrade if required.

Comment: there is no need, mysql 8 has the shown window functions, JSON_table and cte and more, but it still has some problems. and some claim that it got slower, but mysql 6.7 is also old and will be in some time deprecated, so a testrun with mysql 8 should be done in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **MySQL 8** you can use [ROW_NUMVER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) for this

> ```
> CREATE TABLE scansv2 (
>   `SCAN_ID` INTEGER,
>   `USER_ID` INTEGER,
>   `PRODUCT_UPC` INTEGER,
>   `SCANNED_ON` DATETIME
> );
>
> INSERT INTO scansv2
>   (`SCAN_ID`, `USER_ID`, `PRODUCT_UPC`, `SCANNED_ON`)
> VALUES
>   ('100', '1', '0767914767', '2020-08-01 03:49:11'),
>   ('101', '1', '0767914767', '2020-08-01 03:58:28'),
>   ('102', '2', '0064432050', '2020-08-02 04:01:31'),
>   ('103', '3', '0804169977', '2020-08-10 04:08:48'),
>   ('104', '4', '0875523846', '2020-08-10 05:21:32'),
>   ('105', '4', '0007850492', '2020-08-12 07:10:05');
> ```

> ```
> WITH rownum  AS (SELECT `SCAN_ID`, `USER_ID`, `PRODUCT_UPC`, `SCANNED_ON`,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
>           PARTITION BY `PRODUCT_UPC` 
>           ORDER BY `SCANNED_ON` DESC) row_num FROM scansv2)
> SELECT `SCAN_ID`, `USER_ID`, `PRODUCT_UPC`, `SCANNED_ON` FROM rownum WHERE row_num =  1 ORDER BY `SCAN_ID`
> ```
>
> ```
> SCAN_ID | USER_ID | PRODUCT_UPC | SCANNED_ON         
> ------: | ------: | ----------: | :------------------
>     101 |       1 |   767914767 | 2020-08-01 03:58:28
>     102 |       2 |    64432050 | 2020-08-02 04:01:31
>     103 |       3 |   804169977 | 2020-08-10 04:08:48
>     104 |       4 |   875523846 | 2020-08-10 05:21:32
>     105 |       4 |     7850492 | 2020-08-12 07:10:05
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=64eb6a38c70eaff0700afca3f19bd6d9)*

in MySQL 5.x you need user defined variables for the same purpose

> ```
> SELECT `SCAN_ID`, `USER_ID`, `PRODUCT_UPC`, `SCANNED_ON`
> FROM
>  (SELECT `SCAN_ID`, `USER_ID`, `SCANNED_ON`,
>           IF (@product = `PRODUCT_UPC`,@row_num := @row_num + 1,@row_num := 1) row_num 
>           , @product := `PRODUCT_UPC` PRODUCT_UPC
>           FROM (SELECT * FROM scansv2 ORDER BY `PRODUCT_UPC`, `SCANNED_ON`) c,(SELECT @row_num := 0,@product := 0) a ) b
> WHERE row_num =  1 ORDER BY `SCAN_ID`
> ```
>
> ```
> SCAN_ID | USER_ID | PRODUCT_UPC | SCANNED_ON         
> ------: | ------: | ----------: | :------------------
>     100 |       1 |   767914767 | 2020-08-01 03:49:11
>     102 |       2 |    64432050 | 2020-08-02 04:01:31
>     103 |       3 |   804169977 | 2020-08-10 04:08:48
>     104 |       4 |   875523846 | 2020-08-10 05:21:32
>     105 |       4 |     7850492 | 2020-08-12 07:10:05
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b50d3e62e6e857d9a61269fcfb58103)*

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and efforts! That totally worked as expected. Just a quick question: Any ideas on indexes that I can add to make the version with user defined variables any faster ?

Comment: i edit my answer, because the base data must be sorted, hich maswl8 makes automatically   MAke and  INDEX on (`PRODUCT_UPC`, `SCANNED_ON`) and you should also add a where clause, so that you will not have all rows in your table

Answer (score 1):

In most databases (including MySQL pre-8.0), filtering with a subquery is a supported and and efficient option:

```
select s.*
from scansv2 s
where s.scanned_on = (
    select min(s1.scanned_on)
    from scansv2 s1
    where 
        s1.user_id = s.user_id 
        and s1.product_upc = s.product_upc
        and s1.scanned_on >= date(s.scanned_on)
        and s1.scanned_on <  date(s.scanned_on) + interval 1 day
)
```

This gives you the first row per `user_id`, `product_upc` and day, and filters out the other ones, if any.